# Uploading image/images on Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to upload images on an endpoint in postman but i'm getting the error in the screenshot below
Below is my code for sake of brevity i'll only send the affected parts.

Models:

```
class Post(models.Model):    
    content = models.TextField() 
    image = models.ManyToManyField(PostImage,blank=True,related_name='posts_images')

class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post-images',validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png','jpg','gif','jpeg'])])
```

Serializers:

```
class PostImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostImage
        fields = ('image')

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = PostImageSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['content','image',]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        r_data = self.context['request'].FILES
        
        instance = super().create(validated_data)        
        if "image" in validated_data.keys():
            images = validated_data.pop('image')
        else:
            pass
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)    
        instance.image.add(r_data)
        return post
```

Viewsets :

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

[image: Postman response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored the create method of the serializer and it now works

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context['request']
        r_data = self.context['request'].FILES
            
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        
        if 'image' in r_data:
            post_image = PostImage.objects.create(image=r_data['image'])
            post.image.add(post_image)
        else:
            pass
        return post
```